# Gradient effect in QuartzCore

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, quartz-core

I want make UI like the below image. Now I want to make it by QuartzCore.

I had implemented all the Graphics including circles,Vertical and horizontal lines.

I am little confuse how to make that center point with animation effect shown in Image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Dot Image]

The key to the approach used to draw the image shown above is using `CGContextDrawRadialGradient` to draw the dot. We can then use this dot image as the contents of a [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), allowing us to reposition it and animate it as we see fit.

In your original question you asked...

> how to make that center point with **animation effect** shown in Image?

...but as a still image it doesn't show any animation. I've made an educated guess as to how you envisioned the dot be animated.

The following code creates a gradated dot with a pulsating animation, fading in and out repeatedly:

### Code

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat dotDiameter = 30.f;
    CGFloat dotRadius = dotDiameter * 0.5;
    CGRect dotRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame) - dotRadius,
                                CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame) - dotRadius,
                                dotDiameter, dotDiameter);

    CALayer *dotLayer = [CALayer layer];
    dotLayer.contents = (id)[self dotImageOfDiameter:dotDiameter].CGImage;
    dotLayer.cornerRadius = dotRadius;
    dotLayer.frame = dotRect;
    dotLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // Animate the dot to make it appear to pulsate.
    CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
    pulseAnimation.duration = 0.8;
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    [dotLayer addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:dotLayer];
}

- (UIImage *)dotImageOfDiameter:(CGFloat)diameter
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter), NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat radius = diameter * 0.5;
    CGColorSpaceRef baseColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat colours[8] = { 0.56f, 0.78f, 0.94f, 1.0f,     // Opaque dot colour.
                        0.56f, 0.78f, 0.94f, 0.0f };      // Transparent dot colour.
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (baseColorSpace, colours, NULL, 2);

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(radius, radius), 0.0f, CGPointMake(radius, radius), radius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    CGImageRef dotImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *dotImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:dotImageRef];

    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseColorSpace);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGImageRelease(dotImageRef);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return dotImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is from apple, shows how to add shadows in Quarrtz. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html) it is explained

For shadow you can use the right color values nearly equal to cyan color in ur case,

```
void MyDrawWithShadows (CGContextRef myContext, // 1
                         CGFloat wd, CGFloat ht);
{
    CGSize          myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake (-15,  20);// 2
    CGFloat           myColorValues[] = {1, 0, 0, .6};// 3
    CGColorRef      myColor;// 4
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace;// 5

    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);// 6

    CGContextSetShadow (myContext, myShadowOffset, 5); // 7
    // Your drawing code here// 8
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (wd/3 + 75, ht/2 , wd/4, ht/4));

    myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB ();// 9
    myColor = CGColorCreate (myColorSpace, myColorValues);// 10
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor (myContext, myShadowOffset, 5, myColor);// 11
    // Your drawing code here// 12
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (wd/3-75,ht/2-100,wd/4,ht/4));

    CGColorRelease (myColor);// 13
    CGColorSpaceRelease (myColorSpace); // 14

    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);// 15
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i had already used this code But by shadow we cant get the feel of the image i uploaded.

Comment: A shadow is a better description of what the OP is after than a gradient. And it can e animated, with CALayers.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw radial gradient to some CALayer and then just animate that CALayer
Use `CGContextDrawRadialGradient` to draw gradient layer

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
[anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];
// Scale x and y up
[anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:
                CATransform3DMakeScale (1.0f, 1.0f,0.0f)]];
[anim setAutoreverses:YES];
[anim setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];

[gradientViewlayer addAnimation:anim];
```

Hope this helps, I havent tested this, but may be this can give you some directions. 
Other layout you can complete with CGContext

Comment: @CrezyCreator I had Just make animation but I cant get How to make that edge to that Point (Like a Gredient Effect)

Comment: means what sort of edges ?That round circles ?

Comment: The white Round Dot in Center

Comment: That will be what u will be drawing using `CGContextDrawRadialGradient` in CALayer